# getting error while removing the element from queue

Tags: go, queue, runtime-error

```
func (t *bt) topview() {
    if t.root == nil {
        return
    }
    qu := list.New()
    topview := make(map[int]*tree)
    qu.PushBack(top{t.root, 0})
    //fmt.Println(sample.Value.(top).hd)
    fmt.Println("top view")
    for qu != nil {
        sample := qu.Front()
        qu.Remove(qu.Front())
        for key := range topview {
            if key != sample.Value.(top).hd {
                topview[sample.Value.(top).hd] = sample.Value.(top).node
            }
        }
        if sample.Value.(top).node.left != nil {
            qu.PushBack(top{sample.Value.(top).node.left, sample.Value.(top).hd - 1})
        }
        if sample.Value.(top).node.right != nil {
            qu.PushBack(top{sample.Value.(top).node.right, sample.Value.(top).hd + 1})
        }
    }
    for _, value := range topview {
        fmt.Println(value)
    }

}
```

this error I get

```
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x10 pc=0x109e1cf]

goroutine 1 [running]:
container/list.(*List).Remove(...)
    /usr/local/go/src/container/list/list.go:140
main.(*bt).topview(0xc000072f60)
    /Users/pulkitkundra/work/hackerrank/golang-30/tree.go:100 +0x32f
main.main()
    /Users/pulkitkundra/work/hackerrank/golang-30/tree.go:126 +0x108
exit status 2
```

I tried to put the remove line in defer then it gets stuck.
if I don't remove the element it went to infinite loop.
I am trying to achieve the top view code for BST.
Not looking for to create queue in another way.

Comment: I think `qu.Front()` returns `nil` once the list is empty (i.e. once you removed all elements). the loop condition (`for qu != nil {`) will never be meet because `qu` will never be `nil`. you should loop "until the list is not empty": `for qu.Len() > 0 {`.

Comment: making few more adjustments that work thanks. Please post your answer also.

Comment: I added the answer, if it was helpful, please accept it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

panic error is caused by the line

```
qu.Remove(qu.Front())
```

because the element passed to [`qu.Remove()`](https://golang.org/pkg/container/list/#List.Remove) is `nil` and this happens because [`qu.Front()`](https://golang.org/pkg/container/list/#List.Front) returns `nil` when the list is empty (i.e. once all elements are removed)

loop condition

```
for qu != nil {
```

is wrong because it will never be meet since `qu` will never be `nil`.

loop should go "until the list is not empty", i.e:

```
for qu.Len() > 0 {
```

this will prevent `qu.Front()` from returning `nil` and in turn to pass it to `qu.Remove()` and cause panic error.

Answer (score 0):

```
func (t *bt) topview() {
    if t.root == nil {
        return
    }
    qu := list.New()
    topview := make(map[int]*tree)
    qu.PushBack(top{t.root, 0})
    topview[qu.Front().Value.(top).hd] = qu.Front().Value.(top).node
    //fmt.Println(sample.Value.(top).hd)
    fmt.Println("top view")
    for qu.Len() > 0 {
        sample := qu.Front()
        qu.Remove(qu.Front())
        for key := range topview {
            if key != sample.Value.(top).hd {
                topview[sample.Value.(top).hd] = sample.Value.(top).node
            }
        }
        if sample.Value.(top).node.left != nil {
            qu.PushBack(top{sample.Value.(top).node.left, sample.Value.(top).hd - 1})
        }
        if sample.Value.(top).node.right != nil {
            qu.PushBack(top{sample.Value.(top).node.right, sample.Value.(top).hd + 1})
        }
    }
    for _, value := range topview {
        fmt.Println(value.data)
    }

}
```